# Removing DNS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I've got the following DNS records and I would like to ask if it is OK/safe to remove the unwanted entries: admin/ftp/m/mail/webmail (I hope the mail one doesn't affect the emails?)

```
@   IN  NS  ns0.domainname.com.
@   IN  NS  ns1.domainname.com.
@   IN  NS  ns2.domainname.com.
ns0.domainname.com. IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
ns0.domainname.com. IN  AAAA    xxxx:xxxx:x::x
ns1.domainname.com. IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
ns1.domainname.com. IN  AAAA    xxxx:xxxx:x::x
ns2.domainname.com. IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
ns2.domainname.com. IN  AAAA    xxxx:xxxx:x::x
@       IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
@       IN  MX  5 mail.domainname.com.
@       IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx aip4:xx.xxx.xxx.xx ?all"
admin   IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
ftp     IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
m       IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
mail    IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
webmail IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
www     IN  A   xx.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Since most of these subdomains just end up in the apache installation page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mailserver will be located by other mail servers using the `IN MX` record. As the mx record references the server `mail.domainname.com`, removing the `IN A` record for it will break your inbound mailflow.

As for the other entries, if you haven't got/don't intend to use services connected to them, they would be safe to remove.

If you are unsure, they are easy to put back in if you find their absence breaks something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using those names then you can get rid of those A records.

Make note that if you have a server that accepts inbound email at the ip address referenced by the name mail.domainname.com then you won't want to delete that A record. If you don't have a server that accepts inbound email then get rid of the MX record as well as the unwanted A records.